# Thread suspend for exe use cheat engine

Tags: multithreading, suspend

I have an exe and when I suspend the thread of this exe, the anticheat is disabled. But I do not want to use thread suspender every time. These are the addresses called by the thread I suspended. If I "nop" which one using the cheat engine, I will not need to suspend it? How do I learn this?

```
Call Stack:
05F9FB34 7647900F  KERNELBASE.dll!Sleep+0xf
05F9FB44 6B525956  guard.dll+0x65956
05F9FB54 7661FCC9  KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
05F9FB64 777B7C6E  ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath+0x11e
05F9FBC0 777B7C3E  ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath+0xee
```

```
Stack Data:
05F9FA44 77202D20  -> rence
05F9F930 05F9FB48  -> VYRk(#
05F9F410 6B5430C4  -> KERNEL32.DLL
05F9F1FC 6B5430C4  -> KERNEL32.DLL
05F9F190 6B5430C4  -> KERNEL32.DLL
```